# Xamarin Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: The provided scheme is not valid

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, auth0

I currently program xamarin on macOS and i recently updated to the latest version BigSur 11.3 that came out last week. Now When i launch my ios app I get the below error. I'm not sure if its due to the Auth0Client nuget and maybe the apple update affected it somehow. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

When the authentication methods in the Auth0Client runs i get this exception. https://github.com/auth0/auth0-oidc-client-net

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: The provided scheme is not valid. A scheme should not include special characters such as ":" or "/".
```

Comment: I just ran into this issue today after upgrading to the newest version of XF and upgrading Xcode. Hopefully this piece of info helps narrow down the solution.

Comment: This seems to be [a bug has been fixed](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-oidc-client-net/issues/189) and will released then. Maybe you can try the workaround mentioned in this "issue".